# Is there a formal proof to the bridge crossing problem?

Tags: algorithms

You remember the classic problem where you have a group of people on one side of a bridge. Each of them walks at a different speed. Only two of them can cross at one time because they have a flashlight or lantern or something that they need. You can only walk at the speed of the slowest person. Also the flashlight has to be walked back by one of the people.

I saw a video for it on [TED Ed](http://ed.ted.com/lessons/can-you-solve-the-bridge-riddle-alex-gendler) and I was wondering if there was an actual proof for how the problem should be solved.

Comment: ...and what is the problem?

Comment: The bridge crossing problem is finite.  Just create a graph where each vertex is a valid position of people and each edge is weighted by the cost of transitioning to another from one state to another, and find the shortest path from start to finish.